# Conda/pip and package versions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, conda

I am confused by the `conda`/`pip` difference. It seems that when I try to update `scipy` with `pip` I get a very long error ending with `numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found`. But the stranger thing is that `conda update scipy` works but does not seem to update to the latest version of `scipy`.
I am using Windows and recently updated to Windows 10 and deleted "Windows.old" configuration - which I thought might contribute to that error.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `conda` and `pip` are different tools. Do not use one tool to update a package installed by the  other. What is your question? (how to fix seaborn installation?)

Comment: Thanks!
My question is the following:
why is `conda` not updating my `scipy` package?
When I write `conda update scipy`, it seems to _think_ that 0.16.0 is up-to-date, whereas I would like to update to 0.16.1.